# Pod Versioning depth

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have a pod of which the latest version is 1.0.23. Now I want some changes in 1.0.17 version only and not in later versions. Can it be possible to release 1.0.17.1? Is this for level Versioning pattern possible?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the http://semver.org rules, it seems not possible to do so.

A solution could be to increment the minor version to `1.1.0` from the `1.0.23`, and releasing a `1.0.24` with fixes you want to do. But you will have to communicate with your users, because you may have breaking changes with `1.0.24`.